# Homepage redirection after making vistors choose between B2B or B2C client type

Tags: seo, redirects, homepage

We have a site where a business is running since a while, and quite well known by Google. Let's call it example.com . This site is dedicated to one type of client (B2B)

We now want to start the business with another type of client (B2B), and this business will be ran on a subdomain (B2B.example.com).

B2B and B2C are different in the way we are selling, but the product is the same. That's logical to stay on the same domain initial.com, which is the name of the brand. Google ranks it very well too.

I see 3 options:

#### Option 1:

- a client access initial.com (with no previous cookie)
- 302 redirection to example.com/whoareyou
- he clicks on B2B or B2C, and goes to initial.com or B2C.example.com
- we set a cookie with his choice so next time we wont ask who he is and redirect him directly to B2C.initial.com he is a B2C client (302 redirection)

#### Option 2:

- a client access example.com
- if he has no cookie, instead of the homepage, we show a choice page (B2B or B2C)
- when he clicks on a choice, we set a cookie and redirect on example.com (with the standard homepage) or B2C.example.com
- if he has a cookie in the first place we can redirect him to the right site immediately.

#### Option 3:

- replace completely the actual homepage with the "client type choice page" (the new homepage)
- create a new landing page initial.com/B2B which is a copy of the actual homepage.

Which one do you think is best or is there another option?

This last solution is may be the best. The only drawback I see is we may lose the site links we have on Google, because this new homepage will have just 2 links (to B2C.example.com and example.com/B2B), and will not show anymore the actual `<nav>`

Comment: typeA and typeB mean nothing to use so it makes it nearly impossible to imagine he goal. Even still, I would not replicate the site on a sub-domain. I would be using sub-directories and only replicating what is necessary. As well, you will need to consider canonical tags on replicated or nearly replicated pages. If you can tell us what typeA&B are, perhaps we can help with a solution. Cheers!!

Comment: Ok, then let's consider typeA = B2B and typeB = B2C

Comment: The subdomain for B2C is not a replication of the actual site, it's a completely new site with different content and navigation.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense to me now. Thanks! Both are fairly close. Your home pages should be your home page with normal home page stuff, however, the choice should be on that page rather large with some text high on the page in content. Once chosen, set the cookie and redirect. However, always give the user a way back and optionally reset the cookie. Keep in mind that they just got to your site. Give them time to soak it in. Making them chose will likely be off-putting even when there is a clear choice. When you force someone to chose an option, it may not be the option you want. ;-) Cheers!!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a user could be both B2B or B2C.